# Resetting a timer?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having a bit trouble resetting a countdown timer. Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s9bmoosm/2/). It's basically a simple game where you have 5 seconds to select the word that is an anagram of a given word.

I'm basically trying to create a `resetTimer()` function (line 166) that will put the timer back to 5:00 if you've selected the correct answer.

This is the place in my code where I want to call the resetTimer() function.

```
  view.updateData = function() {
    view.assignWords();
    view.displayTimer();

    for(var i = 0; i < this.buttons.length; i++) {
      this.buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        if(event.target === dictionary.correctButton) {
          dictionary.words.pop(this.currWord);
          dictionary.updateWordCount();
          view.assignWords();
          view.updateScore();
          view.resetTimer();
        } else {
          view.displayLossScreen();
        }
      });
    }
  };
```

And this is the code for my timer which starts at 5:00 and goes down to zero.

```
  view.displayTimer = function() {
    var count = 500;
    var timer = setInterval(countdown, 10);

    function countdown() {
      if(count === 0) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        view.displayLossScreen();
      } else {
        count--;
      }
      document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = (count / 100).toFixed(2);
    }
  };
```

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Using and interval to countdown is a bad idea. It will not be 100% accurate.

Comment: I don't think I understand the question.  Technically, if you call display timer again, the timer will reset.  If you want to have a separate `resetTimer` function then it would make sense for you to remove the timer UI updater to another function called `setTime` and just call that in your `resetTimer`.

If you want to take it further, maybe create a module for the timer itself.

Comment: @epascarello yeah, I will probably change it by taking note of a starting time and then getting the actual time that has passed. I'm just trying to get this working first and then I will try to make improvements in my code. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider following changes:

First setting count as global variable:

```
var count = 500;//global variable

view.resetTimer = function() {
    count=500;
  };
```

[**UPDATED DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/s9bmoosm/4/)

### Updates:

Timer was going fast and faster because of line:

```
var timer = setInterval(countdown, 10);//setting new variable with interval every time
```

I have set `timer` as a global variable, and clearing it every time before starting:

```
var timer;//setting global variable
clearInterval(timer);//clearing timer
timer = setInterval(countdown, 10);
```

[**Fixed DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/s9bmoosm/5/)

Comment: There seems to be a problem with this. After the timer is reset, the timer seems to go down faster and faster as you go to the next round.

Comment: Thank you! I made those variables into properties of view instead of global, and it worked nicely :)

Comment: Most Welcome @saadq. Glad it helped you. Enjoy scripting.